# Very basic questions about definitions in Category Theory

Tags: category-theory

I have read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133292/basic-questions-about-definitions-in-category-theory) but I have a more basic question, I think.  I seem don't understand the very concept of a morphism.

As morphisms are described they always seem to be a mapping from one object to another.  In other words, they are a function taking an object and returning another object.  This view is reinforced by the use of arrows in diagrams describing categories where any $f$ "transitions" from one object to another (similar to a state transition diagram).

However, when looking at a description of partial orders on the [Haskell wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory) this doesn't seem to be the case.  There they describe a partial order as a morphism between any two objects $A$ and $B$ `iff` $A \leq B$.  But there doesn't seem to be a 'transition' or mapping between the two.  Just a relationship ($\leq$).  At best this is a mapping (function) taking **2** objects and returning a boolean value.

So, what 'is' a morphism if it isn't a function?

Comment: A morphism in a category "is" a function in the same way that an element of a group "is" a symmetry. That is to say, it is not at all.

Comment: Morphisms can be interpreted as functions in the most familiar examples of categories, but in other categories they can have rather different interpretations. In general a morphism is just an edge in a graph (you can think of categories as graphs with extra structure, namely composition).

Comment: Thanks @QiaochuYuan, the answer below seems to say the same thing.  I was reading too much into the early examples I came across and drew the wrong conclusions about what morphisms are.  I need to go back and look over that material again and think of them as just (directed) edges in a graph and see if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember having had a similar moment when I was first learning about categories. For me it was set off by the opposite category $\mathcal C^{op}$, which is defined by $Hom_{\mathcal C^{op}}(A,B)=Hom_{\mathcal C}(B,A)$ and $f^{op}\circ g^{op}=(g\circ f)^{op}$, that is, the composition is reversed.

This is one of the first examples of a really *abstract* category, a category in which the morphisms have nothing to do with a functional way to get from $A$ to $B$. If I have $f:G\to H$ in the opposite category of groups, $f$ is not a way of getting from $G$ to $H$ at all: it's literally a homomorphism from $H$ to $G$! But the axioms of a category are still satisfied in this case, and in many other useful cases where morphisms are not functions.

To help your intuition about what can be a category-that is, anything that satifies the axioms-you might also look into some finite categories, such as $\cdot \to \cdot$. Here the dots have no inherent identity at all-they're just two unspecified objects with an unspecified relationship between them.

Now, very many categories are naturally *concrete*, that is, their morphisms are functions, and many more can be made concrete. For instance, my finite category above is isomorphic to the subcategory $\{\emptyset\}\to \{*\}$ of the category of sets. But some categories are provably not equivalent to any concrete category, so this thinking straight from the axioms about morphisms is unavoidable.

Comment: So, I guess I was applying a 'familiar' idiom where it didn't belong.  It seems to be the story of my academic life, especially as I try to learn these things on my own.  Thankfully there are groups like this around.  Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is ${\sf Set}^{\rm op}$ concretizable?

Comment: @whacka: yes. $\text{Hom}(-, 2)$ is a faithful functor $\text{Set}^{op} \to \text{Set}$. It factors through a functor to Boolean algebras / rings, and in fact $\text{Set}^{op}$ is equivalent to the category of so-called complete atomic Boolean algebras, although I would prefer to think of these as profinite Boolean rings.

Comment: @whacka As Qiaochu says. This implies also that the opposite of any concretizable category is concretizable, by composing with the opposite of the forgetful functor, so that my example from groups is somewhat suspect: an opp-group map really *is* a function, just from the powerset of $G$ to that of $H$. But there are examples of non-concretizable categories like the homotopy category of spaces.